# Youtube API feedapplying filter

Tags: youtube-api

I am using following rss feed to get videos from youtube. works fine.
       http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zeetv/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile;

now i like to apply certain filter... for example: listing videos which has "Episode" in title.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zeetv/uploads?alt=rss&amp;v=2&amp;orderby=published&amp;client=ytapi-youtube-profile&amp;q=Episode;
```

But it doesnot filter out the videos,which matches "episode", instead it list all.

i had checked this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

and applied query string.

anyhelp is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't query a users videos, like that.

You have to build your query like this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zeetv/uploads?q=Episode&fields=entry(title)

you can read more about the fields syntax here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial#Fields_Formatting_Rules

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after applying fields, still it returns the entire list,not just filtering particular text  . Please check the last video of this link : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zeetv/uploads?q=Episode&fields=entry(title) , where text Episode is not in title

Comment: Well, I see you point. I guess you have to do some post processing of the data to filter those out without episode in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in the question now has the answer. You should perform a search for the term you want and filter by author:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=episode&author=zeetv